# How to show action items at the bottom using Toolbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, material-design, android-toolbar

#### main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_back"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    android:title="@string/back"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
    android:title="@string/save"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_sort"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_sort_dark"
    android:title="@string/sort"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_new"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_new"
    android:title="@string/new_menu"/>
```

#### Manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.app.FileFragmentActivity"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

#### Output:

[image]

#### Requirement:

[image]

I want to show action items at the bottom like in the two screenshots above (marked in red).
I am using `Toolbar`using `appcompat-v7` library.

Comment: I think this method could be work for you @Riser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807744/how-can-i-align-android-toolbar-menu-icons-to-the-left-like-in-google-maps-app

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As stated in [this post (click)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26995040/982852) `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` has been removed in *Lollipop*. Though this is not that big of a deal since you can simply use two `Toolbars` - one at the top and one at the bottom.

Following some basic example code:

#### Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_above="@id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Code

```
private void initToolbars() {
    Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);

    Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
    toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    // TODO
                    break;
                // TODO: Other cases
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
}
```

#### Result

[image: picture showing result]

***Note:*** *Handling when to show two Toolbars or just one is something you have to do manually*

Comment: i am trying your code. but i have problem with setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop). as because i am using this in fragment.

Comment: Hi, a `Fragment` is part of an `Activity`. So you should call this in your Activity.

Comment: Well the simplest option would be to write a public method (`setToolbarTitle(String title)`) in your activity which receives the String and sets it via `toolbar.setTitle(title)`. In your Fragment you call `((MyActivity)getActivity).setToolbarTitle("Lorem ipsum");`

Comment: thanks it works perfectly. i have another small problem. can we show bottom action items from left side?

Comment: I'm not aware of an option how you can do this. At least the `android:gravity` doesn't do anything to the action menu items. Sorry.

Comment: is there anyway to show all the items without the overflow ? like his screenshot ?

Comment: @elpazio as long as you add `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to every MenuItem the Overflow shouldn't be visible unless there're too many icons to display.

Comment: i did that already but the same result :( even with app:showAsAction="always" i get the the same

Comment: six icons but it still a lot of empty space ... on my test device almost 80% of empty space and the items still in the overflow menu ... look here i posted already a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920580/android-toolbar-without-overflow-menu/30920637#30920637

Comment: i think this method could be work for you @Riser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807744/how-can-i-align-android-toolbar-menu-icons-to-the-left-like-in-google-maps-app

Comment: @RahulMandaliya thanks but its already done and I accept answer.

Comment: @reVerse your answer is very good but can you please explain how to align the bottom to right and center ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197213/styling-bottom-action-icon-postion-and-background-color

Comment: @Moudiz As far as I know this isn't possible. You should probably use a custom view which you place inside the bottom toolbar.

Comment: @reVerse I tried in the above link to use custom style like this 
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">70dip</item> but it didnt work .. should I use another way ? do you have an answer similar to my need ? or a tutorial

Comment: @Moudiz I just tried this solution and it works. You have to add `<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>` to the Theme of your app.

Comment: @reVerse I added it in my main menu can you please help me in this ? in this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221561/action-toolbar-icon-design-centered) i explained how I added them. tell me where is wrong ?

Comment: @reVerse I've used the approach mentioned here. But I have a slight issue. Could you have a look at this and try answering it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198838/action-buttons-do-not-cover-the-entire-toolbar

Comment: @ArjunIssar Have a look at the comments here. Multiple users had the same issue and as far as I know there's no other solution than using a custom layout and skipping the whole  `inflateMenu(...)` stuff. Sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to make this toolbar have the same scrolling behaviour as a toolbar placed on the top (i.e could I swipe downwards to gradually make it drop below the screen and swipe up to make it come back) ?

Comment: @user1841702 I haven't tested it but it should be possible. Maybe already with the default scrolling behavior. If this doesn't work, there's still the option to create a custom behavior for the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: And how to get rid of the right alignment of the buttons on the toolbar?

Comment: @Dmitry That's the default when you are inflating a menu into the `Toolbar`. I don't think there is an option to get rid of it but you can wrap a custom Layout in the `Toolbar` and use your own `ImageViews`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make something like this (from the [docs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html))

[image]

or this (from your question)

[image]

then use a [Bottom Navigation Bar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) rather than a Toolbar. It is now included in the support library and isn't hard to set up. See this answer for the detailed directions:

- [How to add a Bottom Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251598/3681880)

Comment: Is there something wrong with this answer? I got a downvote but no comment to help me fix anything.