# How can I align Android Toolbar menu/icons to the left like in Google Maps app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar, android-toolbar

Here is a screenshot of Google Maps Toolbar.

[image: Google Maps Toolbar]

As you can see icons are aligned to the left instead of right (default behavior). I've tried adding android:layout_gravity="left" and android:gravity="left" to the toolbar but it didn't work. I also tried adding an internal LinearLayout (with same gravity values) to the Toolbar but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

I want to be able to use a regular Android menu with the Toolbar widget instead of recreating everything from scratch.

Comment: Just an FYI, I didn't have any issues implementing this using an internal LinearLayout a child of the Toolbar.  I'm not 100% on this, but I think if you use the Toolbar like an ActionBar (i.e. inflating a menu into it) then you're going to be stuck with the behaviors of an ActionBar.  There may be a way around this I'm not aware of though, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: Just add views to your toolbar like so: `<Toolbar ...> <ImageView ... /> <ImageView... /></Toolbar>`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

After some struggling and digging in Android Toolbar code I managed to make it work. Basically, the idea is to add a new android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView as child of the Toolbar, set its gravity to top|start, and then add the menu to that action menu view in your Activity. Here is the code:

#### my_toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tToolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

#### my_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Toolbar-->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tToolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/my_toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### MyActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public final class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  private ActionMenuView amvMenu;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // this layout includes the custom toolbar my_toolbar.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tToolbar);
    amvMenu = (ActionMenuView) t.findViewById(R.id.amvMenu);
    amvMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
      }
    });

    setSupportActionBar(t);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // use amvMenu here
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_activity_menu, amvMenu.getMenu());
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Do your actions here
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @rylexr thank you for your solution. It helped me to create two menu blocks  - one left aligned and another one right aligned :)

Comment: This code has an issue, that if the overflow menu item will appear, it will be next to those items. You should set the width to "match_parent". I've edited your answer for this. BTW, I don't think it's a normal toolbar with action items, either. I think they are tabs.

Comment: `android:gravity="center_vertical|start"` does nothing for me. Why?

Answer (score 5):

If there is no special reason to add toolbar items as menu actions, UI controls can be directly added to the toolbar, and aligned similar to aligning any other item inside a layout.

For an example, following toolbar has a left aligned `Spinner` and a right aligned EditText.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tab_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/categorySpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:hint="Name" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: The benefit of adding items as menu actions is that you get to simplify your XML by delegating the creation and styling of the items to the inbuilt menu feature.

Comment: If you use a toolbar as normal and set the title "ToolbarTitle" but then place an EditText inside the toolbar, the title will no longer display, forcing you to readd it as a TextView.