# How to use SetOnMenuItemClickListener on Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, menuitem

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807744/how-can-i-align-android-toolbar-menu-icons-to-the-left-like-in-google-maps-app), and then I realized that the Java code is not working on C#, I have no idea how to implement this code :

```
amvMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
    return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
  }
});
```

It results the error :

```
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'ActionMenuView.IOnMenuItemClickListener
```

My code so far :

```
tbchild.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.IOnMenuItemClickListener() {
  public bool onMenuItemClick(IMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        return OnOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionMenuView has a MenuItemClick event you can use instead the listener.

```
amv.MenuItemClick+= delegate(object sender, ActionMenuView.MenuItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // your code for the click
};
```