# align menu item to the left?

Tags: android, xml, menu

How does one go about changing the orientation of a menu item? This is what my current menu.xml looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/chat_delete"
    android:title="delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_chevron_left"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    />
```

However, I want to have the chat_delete element shifted all the way to the left. Is this possible through xml?

Comment: I think that your will need to create custom ActionBar/Toolbar in order to do it..

Comment: use this solution [how-to-use-project-layout-inside-library-project-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807744/how-can-i-align-android-toolbar-menu-icons-to-the-left-like-in-google-maps-app)