# How to remove title, and move MenuItem left

Tags: android, list, filter, android-actionbar, material-design

I'm implementing filtering functionality for list. I'm using spinner to select filter. I'm able to show it at ActionBar. However it's right aligned, and I couldn't pull it left in place of title. (Using Support Lib)

I tried to add width, remove title etc, but coldn't make it. It currently looks like this.

[image]

I want this;

[image]

Any idea how do we implement [it](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-behavior)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("")`

Or use NoActionBar theme and add custom Toolbar with drop-down menu to your layout.

Comment: I tried removing title, however It doesn't affect place of MenuItems. I have app wide theme and action bar. So, I really can't change it.

Comment: Tried but 'actionBar.setNavigationMode' deprecated. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this 
getSupportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false).

Comment: I did it, however It doesn't affect place of MenuItems.

Comment: You'll have to create custom toolbar and you can also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807744/how-can-i-align-android-toolbar-menu-icons-to-the-left-like-in-google-maps-app