# How to create vertical BottomNavigationView android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity that have 4 fragment on top and BottomNavigationView with 4 items on bottom. It is working fine in mobile devices. When i go for tablet with LANDASCAPE i want to move that BottomNavigationView to left of the activity with vertical orientation like below.

Is this achievable using BottomNavigationView or should I go for NavigationMenu android.

[image]

Comment: with bottomNavigationMenu, you can't achieve this, however you can try this :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809691/5479863

Comment: You can customize `NavigationView` in `DrawerLayout` to have such UI.

Answer (score 7):

Well i managed to do it, what you want with BottomNavigationView, by some tweaking in orientation change and moving some views.
Firstly for tap into orientation change i added this to Activity tag in AndroidManifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and in my Activity i added following

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BottomNavigationView navigation= (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
            navigation.setRotation(90f);
            navigation.getLayoutParams().width=480;
            navigation.requestLayout();
            navigation.setY(600f);
            navigation.setX(-435f);
           // navigation.requestLayout();
            BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigation.getChildAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i);
                iconView.setRotation(-90f);
            }
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            recreate();
        }
    }
```

and my XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Definitely, you have to change navigation.getLayoutParams().width, setX and setY according to your phone needs. You can create a function to calculate the position. Sorry its 10:30 in the day and was coding all night so going for rest, so couldn't write that function. But i would write that function if you want. Its what i got working for my phone Vivo Y51L, you can have look at screenshots.

Screenshots
[image: Landscape]
[image: Portrait]

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't customize BottomNavigation to be used in a vertical how it's wanted from you.. I would recommend (if you still haven't managed to fix it) switching to this library : [SideMenu-Android](https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.Android) 
Or you can create a customized Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <item 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:title="@string/about"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Put `app:showAsAction="never"` in evey menu item and try...

Comment: I have updated my question. Toolbar menu is not my issue. I want my Bottom Navigation View should move to the left of the activity as in the above image only for Tablet - Landscape mode

Comment: Not yet solved. Just used bottom navigation for both Mobile and Tablet.

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid that `BottomNavigationView` only handles bottom of the page navigation you should create your own custom drawer or use one of the menus [in this link](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Menu.md)
further more if these didn't help you could see [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts) on how to handle different layouts

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You cant move the BottomNavigationView to left area of the layout.

**BottomNavigationView does not meet tablet material design specification**

The only way is You need to check the screen orientation on the start like

```
if (islandcape()){

//Create the Navigation view layout here.. 

}else{

//Create the BottomNavigationView layout here .. 

}
```

Note: You need to write a function to check the orientation and replace the **islandcape()** in the above code

Also try the bellow library that will do the job neatly.

Iiro Krankka https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

[image]