# BottomNavigationView but on the right in landscape

Tags: android, menu

Is it possible to achieve something like that? I would like to have my menu items on the left/right in my app organized vertically (instead of horizontally like standard `BottomNavigationView`).

Comment: like what exactly. ? any code or what you have tried so far would be a good idea to share here... :)

Comment: @Umair i tried with NavigationView https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025879/center-items-verticaly-in-navigationview-and-add-min-max-height and with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985312/bottom-navigation-view-vertical-in-landscape-mode-design

Comment: You could use a separate `layout`  resource folder. `res/layout-land` and create an `activity_main` file in that particular directory to be used when the app enters landscape mode. In this new `activity_main`, you could use a `TabLayout` on the right of the parent. I do not know if it can be done with `BottomNavigationView`. Do give it a try. Could be a fun little experiment.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like `Gmail` in tablets? Give this a try http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/05/android-create-sliding-panel-like-gmail.html

Comment: @meditat yeah, exactly, but not expandable, just icons with text under them (like in BottomNavigationView - the only difference is I do not want this in bottom actually but on the left/right and organised vertically). Thanks, I'll check that

Comment: Gotcha, I'll update you with an Answer. :). But make sure you try it too.

Comment: @meditatI checked that and this is like a standard drawer but with the expandable feature. I want the same behaviour as bottom navigation view

Comment: let's take youtube app menu and imagine we can put in on the right in our app - this is what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

The Library [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) have a **MiniDrawer** with the lots of features.

[image: Mini Drawer]

***See More at Github((https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer))***

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the BottomNavigationView is not intended to work as a "SideNavigationView". If you take a look at the implementation of 'onLayout()' of the BottomNavigationMenuView (nested inside the BottomNavigationView), you will see that it has a hardcoded logic to layout views horizontally.

I think that your best bet will be to write your own implementation of a "SideNavigationView" (e.g. extend the RadioGroup ? -- that's the first thing that comes to my mind).