# Why are menu items aligned so strangely on the ActionMenuView inside the toolbar?

Tags: java, android, toolbar, actionmenuview

Why are menu items aligned so strangely on the toolbar?

[image]

It behaves even more strangely with smaller toolbar:

[image]

I use the following code:

### MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_right, menu);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionMenuView toolbarLeft = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarLeft);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_left, toolbarLeft.getMenu());

    return true;
}
```

### activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLeft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorToolbarText</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

### menu_main_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionAdd"
        android:title="Add"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionDetails"
        android:title="Details"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionLegend"
        android:title="Legend"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionSettings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Why don't you use OnCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: I use it - see the code. My goal is to align some toolbar menu items to the left (in the posted code I'm trying to align all menu items to the left).

Comment: Actually, my code is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807744/how-can-i-align-android-toolbar-menu-icons-to-the-left-like-in-google-maps-app And it works strangely for me. Left alignment doesn't work.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settingsmenu, menu);

        return true;
    }

Comment: Why do you want to do left alignment. It's anti pattern anti design

Comment: I'm implementing custom design that has nothing to do with Android right-aligned menus.

Comment: From the link you have posted, the answer has slight differences with how you have implemented. For example the oncreatedoptionsmenu method. Try matching it and see if it works?

Comment: My `onCreateOptionsMenu` is the same. There is no difference.

Comment: So, why does it give to the 2 buttons too much space and no space for other buttons? I uploaded even more strange screenshot of the smaller toolbar.