# Android toolbar without overflow menu

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to use a toolbar instead of an actionBar since i can't use the split actionbar option, so i implemented two toolbars one in the top and the other in the bottom but im having a problem : that some of  the items are in the overflow menu leaving a huge empty space this is how my toolbar looks like :
[image]

and what i need is somthing like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your xml layout:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

so that your items never appear in the overflow menu.

Comment: hi @adao7000, have you already solved your problem? If yes, pls answer your question, i have the same problem too. Thanks.