# Add icons in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

What is the name of this ? How to design it ? any valid usefull tutorial example ?

[image]

Comment: it's most likely a horizontal linearlayout

Comment: Use Tab-host for this

Comment: I call it a `footer`. It can be any layout (not necessarily Linear) or any View (even a custom one).

Comment: @Sadiq what is tab host

Comment: @Baalback Please follow this link http://envyandroid.com/align-tabhost-at-bottom/

Comment: @Sadiq what is difference between tabhost and split action ? if tab host exists why people use linearlayout design ? I am thinking to post that as another question

Comment: @Baalback check my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) in android

> Split action bar provides a separate bar at the bottom of the screen
> to display all action items when the activity is running on a narrow
> screen (such as a portrait-oriented handset).
>
> [image: splitactionbar]
>
> Mock-ups showing an action bar with tabs (left), then with split
> action bar (middle); and with the app icon and title disabled (right).

**Update:**

In newer UI patterns it is called [bottom toolbar](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars)

> [image: bottomtoolbar] Bottom toolbar that launches to a shelf and
> clings to the top of the keyboard or other bottom component

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482012/how-to-show-action-items-at-the-bottom-using-toolbar) to create one.

---

Note: android does not have text with icon in its UI elements for actions, screenshot in question seems to be of a hybrid application, and suggestions in answer are closest supported by default UI patterns for native apps.

Comment: What is shown in the screenshot is not a split action bar. A split action bar does not have captions below icons, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, missed the text. however all of them are actions and not the tabs.

Comment: A split action bar does not supported with toolbar.

Comment: I'm still upvoting this. Genuinely didn't know it existed.

Comment: split action bar is closest to the pattern shown. this pattern is not recommended for tabs.

Comment: @RahulTiwari what do you recommend then? RelativeLayout ?

Comment: I actually checked again in material design manual a [bottom toolbar](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars) can be used for this purpose.

Comment: @RahulTiwari oh great ill check that . but what is the difference betweent tabhost and bottom toolbar ? do you have any idea?

Comment: @Baalback  tab host is basically for navigation and bottom toolbar is for actions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a linear layout. Whatever you want as long as you make it look good.

The trick is to making it stick to the bottom of the screen. I like to contain everything in a relative layout and set that linear layout inside the relative layout and making it align to the bottom of it's parent.

example layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" is the important part here, but there are other ways to make the linear layout stay at the bottom.

Comment: Do you know examples for that ?

Comment: can you add dummy image with text in your example?

Comment: The layout I posted basically puts three buttons into a linear layout bound to the bottom of the screen. You're going to have to put a little more effort into prettying it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to add buttons in bottom bar :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" style="@android:style/ButtonBar">

    <Button android:id="@+id/saveButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/menu_done" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/cancelButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/menu_cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```