# action toolbar icon design centered

Tags: android

I am having this 2 icons on the left
[image]

I want to make one on the right and one on the center . how to do that ?

this is my style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">70dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">70dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">70dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

this menu main

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />


    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: You need to add `<item android:name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>` to your `CustomActionBarTheme` not the menu itself.

Comment: @reVerse ahh.. can you please tell me where to create the file ? under which folder ?

Comment: Well you already have you `styles.xml` file right? Just add it to your `<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` tag.

Comment: @reVerse yes i did that thank you

Comment: Looks like pretty same as one of your previous questions I have answered?

Comment: @bnk yes it is the same question but different answer

Comment: So, this solved yet?

Comment: @BNK yes bcz it related to the other question

Comment: @bnk hello man can you check this please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296887/icon-disapeared-in-actionbar-after-enabling-a-new-toolbar

Comment: I'll check it when I have free time, busy now :)

Comment: @bnk check it whenever you can thanks man

Comment: @BNK hellp man, can you check for me something? you busy?

Comment: I am going to sleep in 30 minutes, I have answered your above link, does it not work? If you have any new issue, you can comment or create new question, I will check tomorrow

Comment: @BNK hey man yes I saw the answer but I didnt read it honestly , I am doing something with fragments once dont it ill check your asnwer right away .. this is the question that i posted but i guess someone was able to help me. check it if you like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318010/after-copying-the-imageadapter-to-fragmetn-image-is-not-displaying/33318259?noredirect=1#comment54435041_33318259