# Overflow menu in footer in android

Tags: android, overflow-menu

I have created an Option menu and footer with 4 icons on it. I would like the overflow menu icon (Three dots icon) to be shown on the footer instead of top right? Is this possible?

If I put a over flow icon is it possible to access the menu.xml file onClick?
if so how do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have the toolbar at the bottom. search for toolbar at the bottom on stackoverflow you will find examples

Comment: @Raghnandan: Thanks! OK  but how should get overflow menu to shown only on bottom toolbar and not the top?

Comment: you can hide the action bar on top if needed and create a custom layout put that in the bottom of the main layout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482012/how-to-show-action-items-at-the-bottom-using-toolbar

Comment: @Dhina: I have toolbar in the top. I require it as I having couple of buttons there.

Comment: @Dhina: what code do you want?

Comment: of What you have tried !

Comment: I haven't tried any on toolbar part as I am not sure what to start with? As of now I know if I use toolbar I should be able to get the overflow menu but I am not if I can use two toolbars if I do how will I address the overflow menu to show only in bottom toolbar..

Answer (score 0):

First of all set activty theme to `NoActionBar`.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then create a `Toolbar` in XML and set `layout_alignParentBottom` true.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Then in `onCreate` catch the Toolbar and set as `ActionBar`

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.homeToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Create a menu file in `res/menu` folder

Then inflate that menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Then override `onOptionsItemSelected` and do what you want with the items.

Comment: I have the menu showing the toolbar in the top. If I create a toolbar for bottom I would like to show the menu in the bottom and not in the top.

Comment: Yes. I have tried menu.. they come up. the problem they are coming both sides.

Comment: Are you using two Toolbars?

Comment: Then remove the top one.

Comment: As I told you I need both.. there three icons from menu is shown in the top.

Comment: Then you can create a RelativeLayout and set it parent bottom. And then use a ImageView and onClick of ImageView create a PopUpWindow.