# Toolbar placement for Android app in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-toolbar

I know that it is common for Android devices to have its toolbars on top of the page, but I'm also curious if there is a way to set the `Toolbar Placement` to `Bottom` for Android app just like Windows Phone apps do by default.

What would be recommended way to move the toolbar to the **bottom** of the Android app screen?

Comment: You could refer to : https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF

Comment: Thanks a lot for a suggestion. Did you had any luck with suggested implementation?

Comment: You need to write a renderer to implement this feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to place the toolbar on the bottom on Android, as discussed here [How to show action items at the bottom using Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482012/how-to-show-action-items-at-the-bottom-using-toolbar) . Such possibility is not supported out of box in the current version of Xamarin.Forms. You may need to write a custom renderer to make it work in your app. Also it is expected that in the next generation of Xamarin.Forms (v3.0) you'll be able to mix native controls with Xamarin.Forms which will make this fairly easy thing to do by adopting the advice above.

Comment: I've done it in Java (native Android) and in C# (Xamarin.Android). It's a pity that in Xamarin.Forms you can't shift Android toolbars in a simple way.