# How to add a bottom menu to Android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add another action bar or menu to the bottom of my activity layout and keep the top action bar.

Something like this :

[image: My Layout]

Here is my Layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.yasser.version6.PublierActivity">


<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />



<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/profil_image"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="218dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="218dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="Écriver quelque chose..."
            android:id="@+id/publication_text"
            android:maxLength="150"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>


    </LinearLayout>




    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
        android:id="@+id/publication_image"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/default_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried to add a custom RelativeLayout which look almost like an action bar, but the toolbar goes up and mess up everything.

Comment: Check if [this](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/05/making-sliding-up-panel-like-google.html) helps

Answer (score 16):

## Creating custom bottom toolbar

I've already created a simple app which should demonstrate you how to begin

[image]
[image]

#### Creating a custom ViewGroup

Here's my `activity_main.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.piotr.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_pdf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/primary_material_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see my parent `ViewGroup` is `RelativeLayout`, which simply allows me to create a view at the bottom of screen.

Notice that I set layout padding to zero (I think: setting layout margin to zero here is not necessary, the same effect). If you'd change it, the toolbar won't use full width and it won't stick with bottom of the screen.

Then I added a Linear Layout with hardcoded height which is:

```
          android:layout_height="40dp"
```

I wanted it, that my bottom toolbar would take full available width so I set it as `match_parent`.

Next, I added some `ImageButton` views with images from Android library.

There you have two possibilities:

- if you really want to have a toolbar like in above example just remove in every `ImageButton` view this line:

  ```
        android:layout_weight="1"
  ```

After removing weights and some buttons you would get a view pretty similar to expected:

[image]

- if you want to take the full width and make every button with the same size use in your project `weight` as in this mine example.

Now let's go to my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.piotr.myapplication"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In that file I'd added as you can see only one additional line:

```
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

to make sure that device keyboard won't hide my custom bottom toolbar.

If you have any question, please free to ask. I would answer them as quickly as possible.

Hope it help

Comment: as of now you can put toolbar at bottom and then set the action bar there
refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660515/split-action-bar-on-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: hi piotrek, its worked fine but here i want to hide status bar also, is it possible?

Comment: @user512 glad to hear. Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: thanks for reply piotrek. i tried above code, its hiding the status bar but not showing toolbar above the keyboard when keyboard appears.

Comment: @user512 create a new issue on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

I made a custom Bottom bar with exact Height of ?attr/actionBarSize and ` layout_alignParentBottom="true" to put it in bottom.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:weightSum="30"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/iconcamera"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/shape"/>
</LinearLayout>`
```

Now goto Manifest.xml and in your activity tag put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

This will resize the layout on keyboard opening.

Answer (score 0):

That is a split action bar. It is available for handset devices with a screen width of 400dp< To enable split action bar, simply add uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" to your or manifest element.

Edit: The second image is indeed not a split action bar. These are just buttons with the buttonBarButtonStyle attribute. Look into this here.

Comment: There is no link provided "here"

Comment: @yasser 

If this option is activated, Android has the option to split the action bar. Whether to split is decided by the system at runtime

You can define that the action bar should be automatically split by the system if not enough space is available you can activate this via the android:uiOptions="SplitActionBarWhenNarrow" parameter in the declaration of your application activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Add a toolbar and set it to bottom and simply can create your own custom layout.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#333333" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/folder"
                android:id="@+id/pdfViewer"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cameranew"
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```