# Adding menu at the bottom of android application

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, menu

I'm a new user of stack overflow and am having trouble with this particular element in creating my application. Firstly I've come across many threads which however don't specifically image description here cover the design feature I would like to implement within this android app. I don't think it's best to simply make buttons which could solve this issue, as I have multiple pages which alter in content which may lead to the possibility of scrolling to view this menu. I've tried a few different solutions of java code which also aims to implement this however to no avail. Would somebody be available to help.

I currently have this as my XML from my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout_item">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/news_menuBtn"
            android:title="@string/news"
            android:icon="@drawable/news_icon"/>


        <item
            android:id="@+id/calendar_menuBtn"
            android:title="@string/calendar"
            android:icon="@drawable/calendar_icon"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/social_menuBtn"
            android:title="@string/social"
            android:icon="@drawable/social_icon2"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/maps_menuBtn"
            android:title="@string/maps"
            android:icon="@drawable/maps_icon"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/more_menuBtn"
            android:title="@string/more"
            android:icon="@drawable/more_icon"/>
    </menu>
```

Comment: You can refer to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311601/how-to-add-a-bottom-menu-to-android-activity

Comment: Thank you!! A perfect working solution